# change image from list tkinter

Tags: image, python-3.x, list, tkinter

I want my code to be able to change the displayed pizza preview to an arbitrary pizza, but I can't figure out how to phrase it.
(I'm zooming in because I'm using tiny images)

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

class buttonInitialize:
    def __init__ (self,enabler):
        leftframe=Frame(enabler)
        leftframe.pack(side=LEFT)
        rightframe=Frame(enabler)
        rightframe.pack(side=RIGHT)

        pizzaList=[]
        pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="0.png").zoom(10))
        pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="1.png").zoom(10))


        self.otherButton=Button(leftframe,text="??",command=self.makePizza(1))
        self.otherButton.pack()

        self.printButton=Button(rightframe,image=pizzaList[0])
        self.printButton.pack()

    def makePizza(self,index):
        self.printButton["image"]=self.pizzaList[index]
root=Tk()
c=buttonInitialize(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Right now, I'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'buttonInitialize' object has no attribute 'pizzaList'
```

Thank you!

Comment: `pizzaList` is different from `self.pizzaList`.

Comment: I've tried it both ways, and it still throws the same error. Do you know how I can update the image?

Comment: Added an answer. Hope, that clears a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.pizzaList` --> class variable
`pizzaList` --> local variable

To access `pizzaList` in `makePizza`, you should use `self.` prefix to make `pizzaList` a variable of that class when creating in `__init__`.

```
class buttonInitialize:
    def __init__ (self,enabler):
        ...
        ...
        self.pizzaList= []
        self.pizzaList.append(PhotoImage(file="0.png").zoom(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed part of the problem. I'm now getting the error     AttributeError: 'buttonInitialize' object has no attribute 'printButton'

Comment: @I_Queerly_Belong_Here The code you provided above, shouldn't throw that error. There must be a typo somewhere. Your _new_ error has the same source anyway.

Comment: Oh I found the problem, I was just updating the panel with intertools syntax, not raw Tkinter syntax.